# runes within strings

Tags: string, go, unicode, utf-8, rune

I am going through Go By Example, and the strings and runes section is terribly confusing.

Running this:

```golang
    sample := "\xbd\xb2\x3d\xbc\x20\xe2\x8c\x98"
    fmt.Println(sample)
    fmt.Printf("%%q: %q\n", sample)
    fmt.Printf("%%+q: %+q\n", sample)
```

yields this:

```
��=� ⌘
%q: "\xbd\xb2=\xbc ⌘"
%+q: "\xbd\xb2=\xbc \u2318"
```

..which is fine. The 1st, 2nd and 4th rune seem to be non-printable, which I guess means that `\xbd`, `\xb2` and `\xbc` are simply not supported by Unicode or something (correct me if im wrong), and so they show up as �. Both `%q` and `%+q` also correctly escape those 3 non-printable runes.

But now when I iterate over the string like so:

```golang
    for _, runeValue := range sample {
        fmt.Printf("% x, %q, %+q\n", runeValue, runeValue, runeValue)
    }
```

suddenly the 3 non-printable runes are not escaped by `%q` and remain as �, and `%+q` attempts to reveal their underlying code point, which is obviously incorrect:

```
 fffd, '�', '\ufffd'
 fffd, '�', '\ufffd'
 3d,   '=' ,  '='
 fffd, '�', '\ufffd'
 20,   ' ' ,  ' '
 2318, '⌘', '\u2318'
```

Even stranger, if I iterate over the string as a byte slice:

```golang
    for _, runeValue := range []byte(sample) {
        fmt.Printf("% x, %q, %+q\n", runeValue, runeValue, runeValue)
    }
```

suddenly, these runes are no longer non-printable, and their underlying code points are correct:

```
 bd, '½', '\u00bd'
 b2, '²', '\u00b2'
 3d, '=', '='
 bc, '¼', '\u00bc'
 20, ' ', ' '
 e2, 'â', '\u00e2'
 8c, '\u008c', '\u008c'
 98, '\u0098', '\u0098'
```

Can someone explain whats happening here?

Comment: The official docs are probably a better resource, https://go.dev/blog/strings

Comment: @JimB yeah, that is actually where that string in the beginning is from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fmt.Printf` will do lot of magic under the covers to render as much useful information via type inspection etc. If you want to verify if a string (or a byte slice) is valid `UTF-8` use the standard library package `encoding/utf8`.

For example:

```
import "unicode/utf8"

var sample = "\xbd\xb2\x3d\xbc\x20\xe2\x8c\x98"

fmt.Printf("%q valid? %v\n", sample, utf8.ValidString(sample)) // reports "false"
```

Scanning the individual runes of the string we can identify what makes this string invalid (from a `UTF-8` encoding perspective). Note: the hex value `0xfffd` indicates a bad rune was encounter. This error value is defined as a package constant [utf8.RuneError](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#pkg-constants):

```
for _, r := range sample {

    validRune := r != utf8.RuneError // is 0xfffd? i.e. bad rune?

    if validRune {
        fmt.Printf("'%c' validRune: true   hex: %4x\n", r, r)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("'%c' validRune: false\n", r)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/9NO9xMvcxCp

produces:

```
'�' validRune: false
'�' validRune: false
'=' validRune: true   hex:   3d
'�' validRune: false
' ' validRune: true   hex:   20
'⌘' validRune: true   hex: 2318
```

Comment: This is pretty eye opening. But if those bytes are invalid utf-8, then how did I get ½, ² and ¼ in that second loop? After further inspection, it seems that ½ in utf-8 is "\xc2\xbd", ² is "\xc2\xb2" and ¼ is "\xc2\xbc", so they all essentially just needed "\xc2" behind them to be valid utf-8. And yet, the second loop worked without them?

Comment: @FarhanAlvi, when you convert to `[]byte` you are no longer decoding as utf8, you are just converting the type to a series of raw bytes.

Comment: A `string` is assumed to be UTF-8 compliant (since it's backing array is just a byte array - this of course can be junk bytes that is not UTF-8). Your second loop ranges on a byte slice - which is very much different. Here, each raw byte is read - instead of a rune in the string case. A byte is just 1 byte. A rune is up to 4 bytes (under the covers rune is just an `int32`). Scanning random bytes from an encoding like UTF-8 - or any other encoding for that matter - will produce unpredictable results. For instance ASCII bytes are lower than hex `0x80` - and those rogue bytes are above this.